# Benefits to different coding schemes in time series models

Tags: regression, time-series

I have seen spline models in time coded a number of ways-

1. time 1 = 1, 2, 3, 0 0 0 ; time 2 = 0 0 0 1, 2, 3
2. time 1 = 1, 2, 3, 3 3 3 ; time 2 = 0 0 0 1, 2, 3
3. time 1 = -3, -2, -1, 0 0 0; time 2 = 0 0 0 1, 2, 3

etc.

What are the practical ramifications for different time coding schemes when interpretation a regression? Is it all just manipulation of the intercept and interpretation of the model?

Citations: 
Flora, D. B. (2008). Specifying piecewise latent trajectory models for longitudinal data. Structural Equation Modeling, 15(3), 513-533.

Raudenbush, S. W., & Bryk, A. S. (2002). Hierarchical linear models: Applications and data analysis methods (Vol. 1). Sage.

Comment: Pls provide some references on where and how these schemes are used.

Comment: added a few references